# All BFS/DFS trees starting from a single vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Let $G$ be a simple graph. A **spanning tree** of $G$ is a subgraph of $G$ that is a tree containing every vertex of $G$.
A spanning tree can be built by doing a breadth-first search or a depth-first search of the graph.

For example, the following code demonstrates this. We obtain a BFS Tree starting from vertex 1 (considered the root node) during the BFS process.

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 4 <-> 5}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexSize -> {1 -> Medium}];
Reap[BreadthFirstScan[%, 1, {"FrontierEdge" -> Sow}]][[2, 1]] // 
 HighlightGraph[%, #] &
```

[image]

However, the obtained spanning trees during this process are not necessarily unique. The displayed tree below is also a spanning tree rooted at 1 in the BFS process.

[image]

So, I want to generate all spanning trees starting from a specific vertex, following the BFS/DFS traversal order from a given vertex.

We can start with `PetersenGraph[5, 2]` and choose some vertex as the starting point.

Comment: What is the difference between the two spanning trees you show in pictures? They look *exactly* the same to me.

Comment: If you `RandomSample` the edge list you use to construct the graph, you'll get different spanning trees, even though the graph is the same (Mathematica might display it upside down though the connectivity hasn't changed). BFS/DFS are influenced by the order the edges appear in that list. So you can run the search on all permutations of the edge list. Delete duplicates, and I'm guessing you should have all of the trees for that given scan method. Unfortunately there are about 1.3 trillion permutations of the Petersen graph you mentioned.

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry. But these two trees (in red) are evidently distinct.

Comment: @flinty Thank you. This is unbelievable. However, the number of spanning trees of Petersen graph is 2000 (by `IGSpanningTreeCount`). So it must be at most 2000.

Comment: @licheng yes, you'd have to permute the edges, giving 15! permutations to search over until you've counted all 2000 unique MSTs.  A better way would be to start off with the far smaller set of 2000 trees and see if they can be reached via the search method from the 1 node.